# How to simplify the Gamma functions such that the Binomial Theorem can be used?

Tags: binomial-coefficients, gamma-function, binomial-theorem

I have the following expression:
\begin{align}
   \sum^\infty_{k=0} \frac{\Gamma\left( \frac{2k+1}{b} \right) }{\Gamma(2k+1)} (-1)^ky^k.
\end{align}
Is there any way to manipulate this expression to equate to something like $(1+y)^{-n}$?

What I know so far is

1. the factorials can be expressed in terms of Gamma functions, i.e. $n!=\Gamma(n+1)$;
2. The Binomial Theorem: $$ (1+x)^{-n} = \sum^\infty_{k=0} {{n+k-1}\choose{k}} (-1)^k x^k, $$
   since ${{-n}\choose{k}}= (-1)^k{{n+k-1}\choose{k}}$.

Comment: If you recognize that $k!=\Gamma(k+1)$ for integer $k$, why have you not simplified your original expression accordingly?

Comment: Ah, I forgot to simplify this bit - i have edited this part and simplified the expression. Thanks, James!

Comment: For $b=1$ or $b=2$ it can be simplified.

Comment: I can see how it can easily be simplified for b=1, i.e. it reduces to $ \sum^\infty_{k=0} (-1)^k y^k = (1+y)^{-1}$. For b=2, it reduces to $ \sum^\infty_{k=0} \frac{\Gamma\left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma(2k+1)} (-1)^k y^k  $ - how can this be simplifed further?

Comment: If $\,b\,$ is a positive integer, then the sum can be expressed in terms of complicated hypergeometric functions.